# Divide develop space & online space by Git

Tags: git

I'm now working in a website project that is on Windows(Appserv) and I need to 
edit the code on the same machine.

Therefore, I try to find the way to divide the work space.

This is what I think to do it:

```
www/online/.. (here puts the file that is for others to visit

www/dev/.. (here is for me to develop
```

My question is that is it possible to use git to manage two spaces?

For example, create a /git directory as a remote repository then let /dev & /online remote it so that I can control the version between two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Git is a version control system managing files on a file system.  If you want to have two directories in the same git repository that's in no way a problem.

If you want to have `/dev` and `/online` in different repositories, but want them to appear in the same directories, you can use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

> Suppose you’re developing a website and creating Atom feeds. Instead of writing your own Atom-generating code, you decide to use a library. You’re likely to have to either include this code from a shared library like a CPAN install or Ruby gem, or copy the source code into your own project tree. The issue with including the library is that it’s difficult to customize the library in any way and often more difficult to deploy it, because you need to make sure every client has that library available. The issue with copying the code into your own project is that any custom changes you make are difficult to merge when upstream changes become available.
>
> Git addresses this issue using submodules. Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.

Comment: Thanks! I 'll check the submodules!

Comment: I think it is not what I want. I'm trying to have /dev and /online different repositories and also in different directories. I just want to Synchronize these two directories.